# A Leadership Vacuum: Please Step Up

Tags: discussion, moderation

For the last two months, I have been seeking more moderators for this site. Currently, there are only two active moderators: Alan and Pearsonartphoto, and Alan has been on board for about a month. He's been doing awesome, but we need at least one more person.

So, I am turning to the community and issuing a call to arms. **This community needs people to lead it!** Moderation is about accepting edits and handling flags, yes, but it's also about serving as a role model to the community. It's about helping shape the site, policy-wise and scope-wise, into something that can -- nay, will! -- be truly successful, valuable, and *makes the internet better!*

This may seem like a tall order, but I am confident that there is someone who is dedicated to this site enough that he or she wants to take on the position. Furthermore, *you would not be going at it alone*. Moderators work as a *team* to address issues, move the site forward, and clarify the breadth of the site itself. It is a privilege (and a joy!) to be able to look at a community and know you've had a direct hand in building it.

I'll stress this much: this is a voluntary activity. If you opt to step in and then find yourself overwhelmed by Real Life or work or some such, you're free to leave or take a leave of absence, but you'd need to let the Community Managers and your fellow moderators know.

This site needs someone willing to stand up and say, "I want to make this place better!" If you're that person, *please say so!* We'd love to have you. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd hate to see Alan & Pap going it alone - especially since I'm probably bogging down their flag lists when I'm bored.

I'll join in the party, if others are ok with it...

Comment: That would be awesome.

Comment: Congratulations farray...

Comment: @Jack Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 4):

I will also add that being a moderator doesn't take excessive amounts of time. What you are agreeing to is to check the site a few times a day, respond to flags, and generally make sure the site is running smoothly. I rarely spend more than 20 minutes a day doing moderator duties, and most of the time not even that much. And if you have to take a vacation, that's fine. I was gone for over a week when I was the only active moderator. I let the SE team know what was happening, and they took care of the site while I was gone.

Furthermore, it is quite rewarding to be a part of maintaining a site. And there's cool perks, which include being able to see the trends of the site, hanging out with the other moderators in the Teacher's Lounge, having mod powers in every chat room (Except SO and MSO), and generally just helping this network to grow.

Comment: Oh, I could *hug* you~!

Answer (score 4):

It would be fantastic to add Farray to the mod list. His flags, posts and comments are spot on, he's a major asset to the community and a pleasure to interact with. He also has a lot more experience overall with the SE community at large than I do, *and* he's in my time zone, so he's absolutely got my vote. :)

We do need to steer GD in a more productive direction. Farray and a very few (six) others are already on my list for a gallery chat on where we go from here, as soon as my current heavy workload eases off a bit.

Comment: You are ever the wordsmith, and quite gracious to boot.  Thanks for the kind words...